# Using pandas to fill out Python scrip

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

Currently, I have a Python (3.8.3) script that is used to send WhatsApp messages. It gets the name for the phone numbers `names = ['phone number 1', 'phone number 2', phone number 3']`
I want to change this so that all the phone numbers get pulled from an excel sheet.

Currently I have

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('contactsList.xlsx')
names = [pd]
```

The issue that I run into is when the output is printed it is not fetching the numbers in the format that I need to and am not sure how to convert it.
This is what currently gets printed out

```
  phone number 1 
0  phone number 2
1  phone number 3
```

I don't know what I need to do in order to fix it to get it into the format I need without the "0 and 1", and to be formatted in the `names = ['phone number 1', 'phone number 2', phone number 3']` that the script currently works in.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `df` will have a column name for the phone numbers, since you didn't give us that info, let's call it `'numbers'` here. Then you can do `names = list(df['numbers'])`.

If this doesn't work share all the necessary info for us to help, e.g. the content of your xlsx file, `df`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

use list() function to convert np array to list:

```
names= list(df['names'])
```